# Monotouch: device doesn't show up in configuration

Tags: xamarin.ios, provisioning

I edited a provisioning profile to add a device (an iPad 1).  It shows up in XCode Organizer, and the provisioning profiles were both downloaded and copied to ~/Library/MobileDevices/Provisions.

However, when I start MT and try to change the configurations (both at the solution level and the project level) the iPad device does not show up in Platform when I try to add the new configuration (Debug|iPad).

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just pick iPhone for the Platform and when you go into the project's Build>iPhone Bundle Signing>Provisioning Profile, the profile will be available (you won't see the name of your device anywhere in MonoDevelop though. So long as you added it to the profile you select, you'll be able to push your build to the device. The iPhone Application > Target devices is where you specify iPhone, iPad or both. This is independent of the configuration you pick.